# In Docker Desktop, there is no option to "Switch to Windows containers"

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I'm on Windows 11 PRO using Docker Desktop 4.25.0 with Linux containers. I want to switch to using Windows containers and I cannot find a way to switch. This issue is very similar to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149702/docker-desktop-cannot-switch-to-windows-container) except for me the option is entirely missing:

[image]

The solution in other threads is to use `docker-cli.exe` to switch using the command line, but for me, there is no `docker-cli.exe`.
[image]

Any ideas why I can't move to using Windows containers?

Comment: While programmers love to use Docker and other virtual machine and container technologies, they aren't specifically programming tools.  Questions about use of such tools belongs on superuser.com (or sometimes serverfault.com)

Comment: I had this as well. Installing latest version fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:

- Completely uninstalling Docker Desktop (it hung for a good 30 mins on deleting images)
- Manually deleting any left over files in `C:\Program Files\Docker` and `C:\ProgramData\Docker*`
- Rebooting
- Reinstalling Docker Desktop 4.25.0

Now I can switch to Windows containers.